# How to close DataReader in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datareader

I encounter error when executing or loading list of data from database. There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first. i don;t know how to fix it. i don't have any idea on fixing this. I typed dr.close but nothing happens. please help me. if someone know. thank you so much!

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE status='On-process'"
Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim i As Integer

With sqlcmd
    .CommandText = sqlquery
    .Connection = connectionsrvr
End With

With sqladapter
    .SelectCommand = sqlcmd
    .Fill(table) ------------->this is the error..
End With

For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
    With lvlistview
        .Items.Add(table.Rows(i)("dte"))
        With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("tran_no"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("comp_type"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("status"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("sys_name"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("mod_name"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("err_desc"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("trigg"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("comp_fname") & " " & table.Rows(i)("comp_lname"))
            .Add(table.Rows(i)("comp_pos"))
        End With
   End With
Next
```

Comment: Declare all of your database objects locally, not at a class, or global level (scope).  Add a `Using` block for all of the objects which implement the `IDisposable` interface.  Create a new connection for each data adapter.

Comment: Where do you define `connectionsrvr`?  More importantly, where do you *close* `connectionsrvr`?  If you're not closing a previously used connection, there's your error.  The connection object should be kept as close to its use as possible.  You should declare your objects (connection, command, adapter), open the connection, fill the table, close the connection, and dispose of the non-table objects in as little code as possible.  Then use the table afterward.

Comment: sir steven doggart, it worked! hehe thank you so much! thanks for the hint. :)

Comment: sir david thanks. i've learn a lot from you guys! thank you so much!